# time since last reboot: how can i convert?

Tags: java, android, xml

I would like to get the number divided into hours, minutes and seconds since the last reboot then documenting the internet I used this code.

```
    long timeBoot = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
```

The problem is that i obtain a number like 5952063. 
How do I convert it into hours, minutes and seconds? Maybe keeping it constantly updated as it happens in the settings of Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int seconds = time % 60;

int minutes = (time / 60) % 60;

int hours = (time / (60*60));
```

The time you have is probably millisecond rather than seconds in which case you will need to divide by another 1000 - i.e. `time = time/1000` before any of the above.